# How do I overwrite text in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text-files, overwrite

I once got taught how to append a text file ussing the following code, but how do I overwrite the file every time I press button one (nobody taught me that)?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ALPHAVAL As String = "C:\ALPHAVAL.txt"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(ALPHAVAL) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(ALPHAVAL, True)
        objWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        objWriter.Close()
    End If
```

End class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Signature of StreamWriter Constructor is this:

```
public StreamWriter(string path,bool append  )
```

So Change your code :

```
System.IO.StreamWriter(ALPHAVAL, True)
```

to :

```
 System.IO.StreamWriter(ALPHAVAL, False)
```

That tells [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) to Overwrite the file.